# Is there a real C4.5 implementation in Python ? (handling missing value)

Tags: python, pandas, decision-trees

To my understanding, C4.5 comes with 4 improvements compared to ID3:

1. Handling missing values in both training data and "test" data,
2. Handling continuous data
3. Handling costs on attributes.
4. The pruning

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm#Improvements_from_ID.3_algorithm)

However, not one of all decision tree python modules that I found, even the so-called C4.5, handles missing values.

Do you know of a library that handles them ? And it would be great if it can work with Pandas DataFrames "out-of-the-box"...

Comment: Have you considered using the H2O package in Python?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a C4.5 implementation in a popular python library. Your options are :

- Try github implementations such as : https://github.com/geerk/C45algorithm
- Try getting R implementations with rpy package : see over there for an exemple of how that would work (C5.0) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070087/calling-c5-0-in-python